# Can posters be stacked?

Tags: papas-freezeria

In the Flash game Papa's Freezeria (and related games like Papa's Burgeria), there are posters which boost waiting score for e.g. medium sized cups. My question is: if you buy two posters, will it boost your score further, or do the effects not stack?